# Issues with PowerShell generated JSON and CloudFlares API

Tags: json, powershell, api, cloudflare, rest

I am trying to write some PowerShell to update an 'A' record on my Cloudflare account. The code looks like the following:

```
##Configure headers
$Bearer = "Bearer " + $cloudflareAPIToken
$Headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$Headers.Add("Authorization",$Bearer)

##Configure Payload
$Body = @{
    type = 'A'
    Name = 'homepc'
    Content = '8.8.8.8'
    ttl = 1}

$Jsonbody = $Body | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$DNSZoneID/dns_records/$ARecordID"  -Headers $Headers -Body -$Jsonbody -ContentType 'application/json'
```

And I am getting the error

```
Invoke-RestMethod: {"result":null,"success":false,"errors":[{"code":9207,"message":"Content-type must be application/json."}],"messages":[]}
```

My json payload looks like this

```
PS C:\Users\Frank> $Jsonbody

{"type":"A","Name":"homepc","ttl":1,"Content":"8.8.8.8"}
```

If I cut and paste this payload into Postman then it works. Bellow is the code generated by Postman. This works

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/6b5e4cf4634bc20cebc1cd96072c/dns_records/4cb90f1dabfcc63a97055234520' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer zHl3LhnQzRyw1_' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"type":"A","Name":"homepc","Content":"8.8.8.8","ttl":1}'
```

Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this?

Thank in advance

Frank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use CloudFlare but from the error message it looks like you are missing the `Content-Type` header.  Try adding this line:

```
$Headers.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

Edit: The header isn't needed as it was specified using `-ContentType` parameter to  `Invoke-RestMethod`.  On closer inspection of the command line the parameter `-Body -$Jsonbody` has an erroneous `-` in front of the JSON body variable which made the string that was sent `-{....}`.